# Simple page authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to hide access to a certain page on a rails app without using something like devise or sorcery. I want to create a password inside the actual app code, so when you access the page it just shows an input, and if the password is entered is correct, it will show the page. Could I get this done with Javascript?

Comment: it is best practice to do this typed job in server side. So, send request to `controller` and add `filter`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, I'm not in favor of doing authentication on the front-end since it is very very insecure. But if you don't need that level of security you can use this tool:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/epassword/index.htm

That would generate an encrypted password checker which would work to protect your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an AJAX request to check if the password is right, then when the AJAX response finishes, call a callback that shows the div where the page is.